# glibc 'make check' errors when using custom gcc install

Tags: build, redhat, glibc

I'm trying to compile glibc-2.33 on RHEL-7.9

As part of this, I'm using a custom gcc built in house that is deployed down `/opt/custom/`

I'm able to compile and use tools down the custom path properly until running `make check` to check everything out. Make check reports the following:

```
Summary of test results:
    138 FAIL
   4090 PASS
     57 UNSUPPORTED
     16 XFAIL
      2 XPASS
```

Upon inspection of multiple tests, I keep seeing this error message:

```
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
```

and upon reviewing how the test itself is called, I was able to determine that the path to the custom gcc location is not being added in to the `--library-path` call. Example:

```
/disk01/dgardner/rpms/rpms/glibc/SOURCES/build/elf/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /disk01/dgardner/rpms/rpms/glibc/SOURCES/build:/disk01/dgardner/rpms/rpms/glibc/SOURCES/build/math:/disk01/dgardner/rpms/rpms/glibc/SOURCES/build/elf:/disk01/dgardner/rpms/rpms/glibc/SOURCES/build/dlfcn:/disk01/dgardner/rpms/rpms/glibc/SOURCES/build/nss:/disk01/dgardner/rpms/rpms/glibc/SOURCES/build/nis:/disk01/dgardner/rpms/rpms/glibc/SOURCES/build/rt:/disk01/dgardner/rpms/rpms/glibc/SOURCES/build/resolv:/disk01/dgardner/rpms/rpms/glibc/SOURCES/build/mathvec:/disk01/dgardner/rpms/rpms/glibc/SOURCES/build/support:/disk01/dgardner/rpms/rpms/glibc/SOURCES/build/crypt:/disk01/dgardner/rpms/rpms/glibc/SOURCES/build/nptl /disk01/dgardner/rpms/rpms/glibc/SOURCES/build/nptl/tst-robust1
```

This errors out.

If I add on to the `--library-path` manually with the custom gcc install location, the test works - e.g.

```
/disk01/dgardner/rpms/rpms/glibc/SOURCES/build/elf/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path ${PREVIOUS_FROM_ABOVE}:/opt/custom/lib64 /disk01/dgardner/rpms/rpms/glibc/SOURCES/build/nptl/tst-robust1
```

I have so far unable to figure out a way to specify this extra library path during tests.

Does anyone know a way to add this custom library path to the `--library-path` passed in during "make check"?

I've read through the INSTALL guide & README given with glibc, as well as have played around with some of the environment variables specified in configure to no luck.

I have also read through the [glibc FAQ](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/FAQ#Compiling_glibc) for compiling, also to no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more digging, I was able to find a suitable answer under the glibc [release notes wiki for 2.33](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Release/2.33)

Specifically, this snippet:

> If the test system does not have suitable copies of libgcc_s.so and
> libstdc++.so installed in system library directories, it is necessary
> to copy or symlink them into the build directory before testing (see
> https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2012-04/msg01014.html regarding
> the use of system library directories here).